# Is there a parameter in Jenkins that point to who started the job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a parameter in Jenkins that point to who started the job? or How can I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Started by](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Started-By+Environment+Variable+Plugin) or [Build User Vars](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) plugin can help.